# How to send a user to a particular URL using a form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, get

I'd like users to be able to select from a form a `user` and then be directed to `individual/user_slug`. Currently, I am redirecting to `individual?slug=user_slug`. I cant figure out if I need to change something with the HTML form, url mapping, or the view itself. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

#### HTML form

```
  <form action="individual" method="get">
    <label for="slug">Choose a person:</label>
    <select id="slug" name="slug">
      <option value="person_a_slug">Person A</option>
      <option value="person_b_slug">Person B</option>
      <option value="person_c_slug">Person C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('individual/<slug:slug>', IndividualView.as_view(), name = 'individual'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

#### views.py

```
class HomePageView(ListView): 
    model = Person
    template_name = 'home.html'


class IndividualView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'individual.html'
```

#### models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    description = models.TextField()

    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)

    photo = models.URLField(null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('individual', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `onClick` attribute was what I was looking for.

The below HTML gets exactly what I wanted.

```
  <form name="jump">
    <label for="slug">Choose a person:</label>
    <select name="menu">
      <option value="person_a_slug">Person A</option>
      <option value="person_b_slug">Person B</option>
      <option value="person_c_slug">Person C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onClick="location='individual/' + document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;">

  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by javascript.

Create an `onchange` event in `select`, and change the form `action` whenever the selected option changes.

```
<select onchange="change_action()" id="slug" name="slug">
  <option value="person_a_slug">Person A</option>
  <option value="person_b_slug">Person B</option>
  <option value="person_c_slug">Person C</option>
</select>
```

and add a script to your code or js files.

```
<script>
function change_action() {
    document.individual.action = 'individual/' + document.getElementById('slug').value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anything else that would be needed? 
It is still sending users to `individual?slug=user_slug`

```
  <form action="individual" method="get">
    <label for="slug">Choose a person:</label>
<select onchange="change_action()" id="slug" name="slug">
  <option value="person_a_slug">Person A</option>
  <option value="person_b_slug">Person B</option>
  <option value="person_c_slug">Person C</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```